# Array values are not returning using google.script.run

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why my array is not returning. I am using google.script.run function, a JS API. here is my code below:

Code for Google script:

```
function getSearchData(textToSearch){
var arr = [];
     arr.push(["Date","TIME","Status","Any","Fruit")]);
   
 
 Logger.log(arr);
  
 return arr;
}
```

JS codes:

```
function searchTable(){
    var txtToSearch = document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
    
if(txtToSearch != "" && txtToSearch.length > 3){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addSearchRows).getSearchData(txtToSearch);
  }
}


       
   function addSearchRows(arr){
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = arr.length; 
   }
```

there is no error or anything. It only changes the label to '0' which should be 1.

Comment: Is this a typo or does your function really have that `}` before Logger.log line?

Comment: just a typo. sorry

Comment: actually solved my own issue. the data that I push on the array are actually variables. there is one data that is causing error to the entire script. to summarize, that data has a different data type compared to other array data.